# Angular ng-model on input not binding within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to get the input entry {{post.title}} to post upon submit, but only {{post.upvotes}} is posting.  Can anyone see what I might not be seeing in my code?

The result when I submit is 
 - upvotes: 0

When I change {{post.title}} to {{title}}, it posts fine, but I can't figure out why it won't bind to ng-model="post".

```
---
name: home
url: /
---
<br>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-block">
      <div class="grid-block">
        <div id="chatBlock" class="small-12 medium-8 grid-content medium-order-1">
            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
              {{post.title}} - upvotes: {{post.upvotes}}
            </div>
            <br>
            <form ng-submit="addPost()">
              <input type="text" ng-model="title"></input>
              <button type="submit">Post</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="contacts" class="small-12 medium-4 grid-content medium-order-2">
            <div>{{test}}</div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('chatter', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations'
  ])
    .config(config)
    .run(run)
    .controller('MainCtrl', [
      '$scope', 
      function($scope){
        $scope.test = 'Contacts';
        $scope.posts = [
        {title: 'test post', upvotes: 5}
        ];
        $scope.addPost = function(){   
          $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});
          $scope.title = '';
        };
}]);

  config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled:false,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }

})();
```

Comment: $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, upvotes: 0});   What is $scope.title?

Comment: Tried here and seemed to be working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13396/

Comment: @OlegYudovich, your fiddle defnitely works, but I couldn't reconcile it with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you pass post.title at that time you are forcefully binding `$scope.title` of which will never give value. I believe you should do use `post.title` & `post.upvotes` & while calling `addPost` you should pass post object so that it would be easier to push data in `posts` array

```
        <form ng-submit="addPost(post)">
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.title"></input>
          <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.addPost = function(post){   
      $scope.posts.push({title: post.title, upvotes: post.upvotes});
      //$scope.title = '';
    };
```

Comment: This worked great!  That's definitely a better way to do it.  I would upvote your answer but my rep isn't high enough yet.  Do you mind upvoting my question so that I can upvote great answers like yours?

Comment: @Todd Williams you can do upvote now.Glad to help you.. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, my rep is high enough now, actually.

Comment: Panka, $scope.post.title = ' '; doesn't clear the input field upon submission.  Am I referencing that correctly?

Comment: @you if you want to clear array then use `post.title=''`, because we have not added that field in scope at all

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

1. Initialize `$scope.title` in your controller, for instance

   ```
   $scope.title = '';
   $scope.test  = 'Contacts';
   ...
   ```
2. Pass `title` as a parameter to `addPost` (and then use the parameter):

   ```
   <form ng-submit="addPost(title)">
     <input type="text" ng-model="title"></input>
     <button type="submit">Post</button>
   </form>
   ```
3. Don't use `title` directly but create an object such as `$scope.model.title`. It is more reliable to use object property rather than directly raw types.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried this but it didn't appear to work.